# Making a speedy custom filter for numpy 3D arrays

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numba

Overall I want to make a filter to calculate [the mean of circular quantities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_of_circular_quantities) on 3D numpy arrays.

I have looked into the scipy.ndimage.generic_filter but I couldn't make the filter compile as described in [https://ilovesymposia.com/tag/numba](https://ilovesymposia.com/tag/numba/), apparently due to a numba bug in windows.

Then I tried to make my own implementation that loops through the array and hoped to be able to jit it afterwards. It runs fine (and slow) without numba, but the jit compilation fails, and I cant decode the TypingError.

numpy's meshgrid is not supported so the behavior of that had to build (a cheap version) of that too.

```
from numba import njit
import numpy as np

@njit
def my_meshgrid(i_, j_,k_):
    #Note: axes 0 and 1 are swapped!
    shape = (len(j_), len(i_), len(k_))
    io = np.empty(shape, dtype=np.int32)
    jo = np.empty(shape, dtype=np.int32)
    ko = np.empty(shape, dtype=np.int32)
    for i in range(len(i_)):
        for j in range(len(j_)):
            for k in range(len(k_)):
                io[j,i,k] = i_[i]
                jo[j,i,k] = j_[j]
                ko[j,i,k] = k_[k]
    return [io,jo, ko]
t3 = my_meshgrid(range(5), range(5,7), range(7,10))
#

@njit
def get_footprint(arr, i , j , k, size=3):
    s = size
    ranges = [range(d-s+1+1,d+s-1) for d in [i,j,k]]
    #Mirror the case where indexes are less than zero
    ind = np.abs(np.meshgrid(*ranges))
    #Mirror the case where indexes are higher than arr.shape:
    for d in range(len(arr.shape)):
        indd = ind[d] - arr.shape[d]
        indd *= -1
        indd = np.abs(indd)
        indd *= -1
        ind[d] = indd
    return arr[ind]


@njit
def mean_angle_filter(degrees, size = 3):
    size = [size]*len(degrees.shape)
    out = np.empty_like(degrees)
    for i in range(degrees.shape[0]):
        for j in range(degrees.shape[1]):
            for k in range(degrees.shape[2]):
                out[i,j,k] = mean_angle(get_footprint(degrees, i,j,k,3))
    return out


@njit
def mean_angle(degrees):
    '''
    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_of_circular_quantities
    '''
    x = np.mean(np.cos(degrees*np.pi/180))
    y = np.mean(np.sin(degrees*np.pi/180))
    return np.arctan2(y,x)*180/np.pi


degrees = np.random.random([20]*3)*90
mean_angle_filter(degrees)
```

Being new to numba I would be happy to get a fix for this (or similar) implementation, but any (speedy) implementation of the mean_angle filter in numpy would also be appreciated

Comment: I don't think I understand what footprint is trying to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your code quite a lot:

1. Mirroring at the boundaries can be done using [`np.pad()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html)
2. Overlapping windowing of the data can efficiently be done using SciKit-Image's [`skimage.util.view_as_windows()`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows).
3. Calculating the mean over an axis can be done using `np.mean(..., axis=x)` where `x` is an `int` or a `tuple` of `int`s denoting the axes you want to mean over.

Put that all together and you get a very simple vectorized implementation like

```
import numpy as np
import skimage

def mean_angle(degrees, axis=None):
    '''
    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_of_circular_quantities
    '''
    x = np.mean(np.cos(degrees*np.pi/180), axis=axis)
    y = np.mean(np.sin(degrees*np.pi/180), axis=axis)
    return np.arctan2(y,x)*180/np.pi


out = mean_angle(
    skimage.util.view_as_windows(
        np.pad(degrees, (1, 1), mode='symmetric'),
        window_shape=(3, 3, 3)
    ),
    axis=(-1, -2, -3)
)
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks. I always appreciate learning new tricks in numpy too. Then I will loose my numba virginity another time.